# When I press the button, show me this error

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I followed this tutorial:

https://suragch.medium.com/playing-short-audio-clips-in-flutter-with-just-audio-3c80eb7eb6ea

But when I press the button I get this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelJustAudio.init (package:just_audio_platform_interface/method_channel_just_audio.dart:13:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1260:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: You can find you answer on https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/452 or raise an issue on the `just_audio` plugin repository.

Comment: I've updated the source code and the tutorial to use the latest version of just_audio. I didn't get the error you were talking about. Let me know if you are still getting it.